# Target symbol by ID from external SVG file

Tags: svg

The goal is to create multiple buttons (in my case two) with different symbols based on one SVG. 
I have an SVG file containing 3 groups with vector shapes.
One group is background that needs to be filled by particular color (hover).
Two other groups contain different symbols (ellipse,square) and named with ZZZ at the end.
One button should show ellipse, another button-square. 
I've set these two groups in SVG to "display:none" unless they are targeted.Content of the test.svg as follow:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 22 22"><defs><style>
  .cls-1 {
    fill: #340000;
  }
  .cls-2 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  }
[id$=zzz] { display: none; }
g:target { display: block; }        
</style></defs><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="test"><g id="group_background" data-name="group background"><rect id="shape_background" data-name="shape background" class="cls-1" width="22" height="22"/></g><g id="square_zzz" data-name="square zzz"><rect id="shape_square" data-name="shape square" class="cls-2" x="4.731" y="4.237" width="13.119"height="13.119"/>
  </g>
  <g id="ellipse_zzz" data-name="ellipse zzz">
    <circle id="shape_ellipse" data-name="shape ellipse" class="cls-2" cx="11.29" cy="10.797" r="6.693"/>
  </g></g></g></svg>
```

In my CSS I'm trying to show different shapes on the buttons:

```
.button1{background-image:url(test.svg#square_zzz);}.button2{background-image:url(test.svg#ellipse_zzz);}
```

However nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Question dismissed. Targeting ID works fine - ( Dreamweaver Live view issue).
Still trying to figure out how to change color for background and shape on targeting group with CSS and implement cloneNode() to duplicate button without creating multiple SVG instances for each button.